Datadog how to group by content
I am trying to do a very simple thing. I wanna groupt the logs via their messages.
However I don't know what to put here in the by field.

Is this possible? To group by the logs by their contents, they appear in the content column however @content did not work for grouping them.

message is the reserved log attribute. However that may not give you what you are looking for.
The log pattern inspector may be helpful. It is designed to aggregate similar log message together to identify interesting patterns - noisy logs that can be filtered, new patterns, groups of patterns all starting at the same time, etc.

the patterns option for group-by worked out of the box for me, thanks
